# How bad can be the behavior of Lebesgue integrable functions?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Let f be a function in $L^1(a, b)$, with $(a, b)$ a real interval, and :

$E+ := \{ x \in (a, b): f(x) > 0 \}$   a non-null set,

$E  := \{ x \in (a, b): f(x) = 0 \}$    a null set,

$E- := \{ x \in (a, b): f(x) < 0 \}$    a non-null set.

Is it possible for $E+$ and $E-$ to have both empty interior robustly ?

(Namely: so that interior emptiness is not lost by changing f on a null set.)

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a Borel set $B$ such that, for every interval $(u, v)$ (with $u<v$), we have $$0<m(B\cap (u, v))< v-u,$$ that is, $B$ is neither null nor full measure on $(u, v)$. (See e.g. [Construct a Borel set on R such that it intersect every open interval with non-zero non-"full" measure](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/961745/construct-a-borel-set-on-r-such-that-it-intersect-every-open-interval-with-non-z).)

Now let $f(x)=1$ if $x\in B$ and $f(x)=-1$ if $x\not\in B$. If you like (as your question is phrased), restrict $f$ to some interval $(a, b)$.

Comment: Note that this is really the only way to solve the question - if $f$ is a function as desired, then $E-$ (or E+) has non-zero, non-full measure on every subinterval of $(a, b)$.