# measurable set and complement in $[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

How can I Construct a measurable set A contained in C = [ 0, 1] such that for an arbitrary open interval B contained in C, $m(A\cap B)> 0$ and $m(CA\cap B)> 0$, CA is the complement respect to C.

My ideas give some of the measures zero, or can I construct with borel sets? Thanks.

Comment: Is that funny symbol y in your condition meant to be AND (or $\wedge$)?

Comment: yes the word is and.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/961770/169852

Comment: but $F_\sigma$ does not apply.

Comment: if $F_\sigma \subset [0,1]$ and $F_\sigma \neq [0,1]$, $F_\sigma \cap B= \varnothing$ for some B.

Comment: @J.Natch If by $F_\sigma$ you mean the set $M$ constructed in the answer linked above, then what you have written is false. If $B$ is any open interval then it contains one of the $I_k$'s (an interval with rational endpoints) and therefore $B$ contains $M_k$. Then, since $M_K \subseteq M$, we have $M_k = M_k \cap B \subseteq M \cap B$, whence $0 < m(M_k) \leq m(M \cap B)$.

Comment: soorry i read wrong, is necessary that $M_k$ be nowhere dense?

Comment: I dont see nowhere density as required condition in my problem.