# Lebesgue measurable set whose intersection has positive measure

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure

> $(a)$ Let $E\subset [0,1]$ be Lebesgue measurable.  Suppose there exists a fixed $\epsilon > 0$ such that $m(E\cap (a,b))\geq \epsilon|a-b|$ for any interval $(a,b)\subset [0,1]$.  Show that $m(E) = 1$
>
> $(b)$ Give an example of a Lebesgue measurable set $E\subset [0,1]$ with $0<m(E)<1$ and $m(E\cap(a,b))>0$ for all nontrivial intervals $(a,b)\subset [0,1]$.  Explain why this example does not contradict part $(a)$

My thoughts:

(a) if $m(E)<1$, then $\exists U$ open s.t. $U$ is the countable union of intervals, $E\subset U$, and $m(U)\leq (1-m(E))/2$.  Then $U^c$ will be disjoint with $E$ and will contain some interval whose intersection with $E$ will have positive measure.

(b) I'm at a lost on how to construct $E$.

Comment: See the answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/961745/construct-a-borel-set-on-r-such-that-it-intersect-every-open-interval-with-non-z).

Comment: I think that the proof for (a) you present is missing. It is possible that U is a countable union of intervals and is not the whole [0,1], and still [0,1]\U does not contain any interval. For instance, U may be a union of intervals around the rationals and of measure, say, 1/2.

Comment: For part a, your proof is indeed not correct, 
for a proof that works see this question  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4590931/prove-that-there-do-not-exist-a-lebesgue-measurable-set-with-the-following-prope/4613350#4613350

The proof there is for $\varepsilon =1/2$ but the idea generalizes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check page $74$ of Fremlin’s “Measure Theory - Volume $1$”, part $(b)$ of $134J$ (“more examples”). [Here’s](https://wiki.math.ntnu.no/_media/tma4225/2011/fremlin-mt1.pdf) a link to the pdf.