# Construct a Borel subset $A$ of $\mathbb{R}$ such that $0 < m(A \cap I) < m(I)$ for every open interval $I$.

Tags: measure-theory, proof-verification

> Let $m$ be Lebesgue measure. Construct a Borel subset $A$ of $\mathbb{R}$ such that $0 < m(A \cap I) < m(I)$ for every open interval $I$.

This question has been discussed before on this site, for example, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/961745/construct-a-borel-set-on-r-such-that-it-intersect-every-open-interval-with-non-z).

However, I came up with a much simpler solution than the other answers on this site, so I am worried there is something wrong with it.

Suppose $I$ is an open interval. For any set $A$, we define the set $cA = \{ca : a \in A \}$. Let $A = \frac{1}{2}I$. The set $A$ is also an interval and is therefore a Borel set. Since $m(cA) = \lvert c \rvert m(A)$, we have that $m(A \cap I) = m(\frac{1}{2} I) = \frac{1}{2} m(I)$. Then we have
$$
0 < m(A \cap I) = \frac{1}{2} m(I) < m(I)
$$
as required.

Is there something wrong with this proof?

Comment: It only works for **one** interval.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I see! Thank you! I knew it was something simple. :(

Comment: In addition, if $I=[4,6]$, then $A=\frac12I=[2,3]$, hence $A\cap I=\emptyset$, also in violation of your requirement. But the main point, as Lord Shark said, is to find a set that works for any interval.