# Can a set of positive measure and its complement both have empty interior?

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, examples-counterexamples, cantor-set

This might be silly, but I am not sure:

Does there exist a Lebesgue measurable subset $E \subseteq (0,1)$ such that

1. $E$ and $(0,1) \setminus E$ both have positive Lebesgue measure.
2. $E$ and $(0,1) \setminus E$ both have empty interiors.

If we relax condition $1$, then $E=Q\cap (0,1)$ works. If we relax condition $2$, then the [fat Cantor set does the job](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith%E2%80%93Volterra%E2%80%93Cantor_set). (Its complement have non-empty interior though).

Comment: In my answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/961745/construct-a-borel-set-on-r-such-that-it-intersect-every-open-interval-with-non-z) I constructed an $F_\sigma$ set $M\subseteq\mathbb R$ such that $0\lt m(M\cap I)\lt m(I)$ for every interval $I$, where $m$ denotes Lebesgue measure. Obviously the sets $M$ and $\mathbb R\setminus M$ have positive Lebesgue measure and have empty interiors, and the same goes for the sets $E=M\cap(0,1)$ and $(0,1)\setminus E$.

Comment: What irrationals on $(0,\frac12)$ with rationals from $(\frac12,1)$ aren't good enough for you? Since when did you become so picky? Are things really that bad since I left?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $E$ be the union of $(0,1) \setminus \mathbb Q)\cap (0,\frac  1 2]$ and $\mathbb Q\cap (\frac   1 2,1)$. Then $E$ and $(0,1)\setminus E$ both have positive measure and they have no interior.

Answer (score 2):

Let $E$ be a fat Cantor set $C$ together with the $C^\complement\cap\mathbb Q$.